# Jquery não passa o valor POST de um formulário

Tags: php, jquery

Colegas

Tenho um formulário do qual estou usando o jquery para passar os valores, porém o valor não passa para o arquivo enviar.php. Vejam:

```
    <form method="post" name="post" id="contact-form">  
                    <div id="success"></div>
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Matéria:</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </div>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="NovaMateria" maxlength="150" id="tirarEspacos">
                    </div>
    </form>   

<script type="text/javascript">    
    $('#submit').click(function() {
      $.post("enviar.php", $(".contact-form").serialize(), function(response) {
        $('#success').html(response);
    $('#tirarEspacos').val('');     
      });
      return false;
    });
  </script>
```

enviar.php

```
<?php 
echo $_POST['NovaMateria'];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neste trecho você está tentando recuperar um elemento de forma incorreta, o `.` indica a classe do elemento, por isso nada é serializado.

```
$.post("enviar.php", $(".contact-form").serialize(), function(response) {
                       ^^^
```

Experimente substituir pelo indicador de ID, `#`, como no exemplo a baixo:

```
$.post("enviar.php", $("#contact-form").serialize(), function(response) {
                       ^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

Além de estar recuperando de forma incorreta `$(".contact-form").serialize()` em vez de `$("#contact-form").serialize()` já que na tag form utilizou id e não classe, não existe também o botão para submeter os dados. O código seria assim:

Código HTML:

```
<form method="post" name="post" id="contact-form">  
      <div id="success"></div>
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Matéria:</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
           <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="NovaMateria" maxlength="150" id="tirarEspacos">
     </div>
     <button id="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Código Jquey:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $('#submit').click(function() {
      $.post("enviar.php", $("#contact-form").serialize(), function(response) {      
        $('#success').html(response);
        $('#tirarEspacos').val('');  
      });
      return false;
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Olá Glauber. Na verdade o botão tinha, eu que esqueci de colocar aqui, mas a mudança do $("#contact-form").serialize() funcionou.